# invalid header file while using jar for archiving

Tags: java, jar

When i use this cmd line :
jar cmf arshad.mf ars.jar *.class 
i get this error :

```
invalid header field name:Manifest-version
```

This is my manifest file :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class:t
```

i made the manifest file with notepad in UTF-8 encoding - is there any problem with the manifest ?

Comment: Hey guys, remember to upvote this question and the answer if this helped you! A question should have a lot more than 1 vote if it has 5K+ views!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add a space after the colons:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: t
```

Comment: thxxxxxxxxxxxxx a lot I was searching a lot with no helpful result!! I wrote:
"Main-Class : MainFram"
After I read your answer I wrote : "Main-Class: MainFram" and it worked !!! thank you so much  @Adam Rosenfield

Answer (score 0):

Yes,it is true.

A common mistake people make when writing their manifest files for jar's is that they don't put spaces after their colons. I don't know, based on what you wrote here, if that's it or not but give it a try.

Example:

```
Main-Class:someClass //wrong
Main-Class: someClass //correct
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, your manifest file must be saved as UTF-8. You're not necessarily safe writing it on MS Notepad and saving as UTF-8 encoding. This post has some good details:

[Invalid Header Field Name when adding manifest to JAR using Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320631/invalid-header-field-name-when-adding-manifest-to-jar-using-eclipse)

Notepad adds some bytes onto the front to broadcast the endian-ness of the data. This will break the jar command. A decent solution is to not use Notepad and download Notepad++. In Notepad++ you select 'encoding' from the top bar, and select 'UTF-8 Without BOM'. Saving your manifest file with this setting applied should solve the problem. If there are no others.