# Invalid Header Field Name when adding manifest to JAR using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, applet, manifest

I'm using eclipse to develop a java applet and need to add an external jar to Class-Path in the manifest. I created the manifest file using notepad, used UTF-8 encoding and added the line break at the end, but attempting to add even a simple example manifest during jar creation results in the following error from Eclipse.

```
invalid header field name: ï>¿Manifest-Version
invalid header field name: ï>¿Manifest-Version
```

I have a feeling that it's some simple configuration issue, but I can't figure out what.

To test it, my manifest consists of the single line

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notepad save your file with a [special mark named 'BOM'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning : 2 bytes (U+FEFF) which identify UTF-8 format.

You have to edit the file with [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/fr/) (or vi) and encode it as UTF-8 (without BOM).

Next steps to make JARs:

- Using eclipse
- Using [Apache ANT](http://ant.apache.org/)
- Using [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)

Comment: That was it! I spent a good couple of hours trying to figure that out. Thanks a lot! I just found out about ANT, so I'll definitely look into that.

Comment: Yes ANT is THE solution for cross platform complex project, later you'll see MAVEN (another step)

Answer (score 1):

In **Notepad++** , from the **encoding** menu , choose **encode in UTF-8 without BOM** .

Comment: Great practical advice to remove BOM, upvote to improve visibility.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, right click in file properties and choose text file encoding to ISO-8859-1

Back in editor delete the special chars.